# Increase number of threads based on resource(CPU or Memory) on the computer.In c programming

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

Have a thread queue with a maximum size of N threads(Using p_threads in C). I want to increase or decrease the maximum size of the queue based on the available CPU or RAM.Each threads performs a WMI query(Network call) and processes the result. But we can ignore the network utilization for now.

How do I go about with this safely?

Comment: You should also take into consideration how often you plan to do this. This is total overhead.

Comment: Determining how much resources you are going to use on the base of how much is available is maybe not the best strategy. You should rather base that decision on *how much you are going to need*

Comment: @TonyTannous: Though I'm planning to do this in a schedule, it might be running almost all the time.

Comment: @tofro: How much resource I would be needing depends on the data being obtain from the devices using WMI query.Planning on monitoring CPU and memory once every 2 minutes and increase the number of threads if total CPU/memory used is not greater than 2/3 of the total available CPU/memory. Would also check CPU/memory every time a thread is allocated for a host for collection. If the 2/3 criteria is not met then that thread is freed. Think its sufficient to perform the check only when event collection from a new host needs to be done. comments please